# Simple python calculator

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, calculator

I'm very new to Python, and so I'm trying to learn it by doing simple programs, like a calculator. But I don't know if this is the "Pythonic" way to do it, or if I am making beginner errors.

So could someone please tell if something is wrong with it, and how to improve it?

Here is some sample input and output:

```
Enter the first number: 2
Enter the second number: 10
Enter an operator (valid operators are +, -, *, / and pow): pow
1024.0
```

Here is the code

```
#A basic calculator which supports +, -, *, / and pow

def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def sub(a, b):
    return a - b

def mul(a, b):
    return a * b

def div(a, b):
    return a / b

def pow(a, b):
    return a ** b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            number1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
            number2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
        except:
            print("That is not a number!")
            continue

        operator = input("Enter an operator (valid operators are +, -, *, / and pow): ")

        #Check if user operator is a valid one
        if operator == "+":
            func = add
        elif operator == "-":
            func = sub
        elif operator == "*":
            func = mul
        elif operator == "/":
            func = div
        elif operator == "pow":
            func = pow
        else:
            print("Invalid operator!")
            continue

        #Print result
        print(func(number1, number2))
```

Comment: How do _you_ quit the program?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I just kill the process, not very user friendly but it works :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a beginner this is pretty good.
But, there are three glaring problems with it.

1. You should use a 'main' function.
2. You should use a dictionary.
3. [`operators`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html)

Starting with (2), a dictionary holds a key value pair.
If you've come across lists/arrays, it's like them,
apart from that you can use a lot of different types,
not just integers.

Defining one is pretty easy,
and using it will reduce your amount of code.

```
operators = {
    "+": add,
    "-": sub,
    "*": mul,
    "/": div,
    "pow": pow
}
```

This will define an object to hold all the operators that you can use.
Now all we need to do is use it.
Using [`operators.get`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) it's easy.

```
func = operators.get(operator, None)
if func is None:
    print("Invalid operator!")
    continue
```

Lovely and simple.

The main function is simple, just move everything in `if __name__ == '__main__':`
into a function.
With the operator addition you shouldn't really need to make smaller functions,
but it may be a good idea, making a function to get user input, could be a good idea.
But it's up to you.
If you did want to do both of these, you'd do something like:

```
def main():
    while True:
        number1, number2, operator = get_user_input()
        func = operators.get(operator, None)
        if func is None:
            print("Invalid operator!")
            continue

        print(func(number1, number2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Just to note, you may not want to make `get_user_input`.

Something that you may not know is you can use the builtin operators library.
This will allow you to remove all your definitions of `add`, `sub`, etc.
And will allow you to change operators to:

```
import operator

operators = {
    "+": operator.add,
    "-": operator.sub,
    "*": operator.mul,
    "/": operator.truediv,
    "pow": operator.pow
}
```

There's some history about Python's division, and that's why it's called `truediv`, but if you haven't and won't use Python2, then you don't really need to know.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `operators`

Comment: should I only call the `main` function if `__name__` is equal to `__main__`, or should I just call it, ignoring it?

Comment: @BlitzRakete: Only if it is `__main__`.  If you were to do it whatever `__name__` equaled, the `if` would be pointless.  As it is, it is checking if the file is being run as a program vs. being imported.

Comment: @BlitzRakete: It's a pleasure.  For more information, see [What does if \_\_name\_\_ == “\_\_main\_\_” do?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/5827958)

Answer (score 6):

**1**

Despite the fact that bare **`except`** works, it would be nicer to be more explicit about what exception you are catching. I would write

```
except ValueError:
```

**2**

**`pow`** shadows away the function provided by Python; I would rename it to, say, **`mypow`**. Not that it matters in this case, but in a larger program you should not do this: finding bugs due to a shadowed identifier is hard.

**3**

You can rewrite the actual logic much more succintly by using a dictionary mapping the name of an operator to the actual function performing the operation.

**Summa summarum**

All in all, I had this in mind:

```
    def add(a, b):
        return a + b


    def sub(a, b):
        return a - b


    def mul(a, b):
        return a * b


    def div(a, b):
        return a / b


    def mypow(a, b):
        return a ** b


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        operator_map = {"+": add, "-": sub, "*": mul, "/": div, "pow": mypow}

        while True:
            try:
                number1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
                number2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not a number!")
                continue

            operator = input("Enter an operator (valid operators are +, -, *, / and pow): ")
            print(operator_map[operator](number1, number2) if operator in operator_map else "Invalid operator!")
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Don't ever use `input` in a function that does work. It violates "separation of concerns" by tying the abstract calculation logic to the means by which the input is obtained.

Far better would be:

```
def binary_operation(operation, left, right):
    """Returns the result of applying operation to its arguments."""
    return operator_map[operation](left, right)
```

where `operator_map` is taken from @coderodde's answer. This allows you to call your (simple) engine in ways that have no connection to how the operands get there. For example:

```
binary_operation('+', 2, 3)
binary_operation(sys.argv[1], float(sys.argv[2]), float(sys.argv[3]))
```

you can also have the original behavior with

```
binary_operation(input('operator'), float(input('number')), float(input('number'))
```

or even

```
binary_operation('*', 5.0 binary_operation('+' 2, 3))
```

Prior to posting, I find that Joe Wallis suggested this, but I think it important enough to elaborate on its own.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to define all of those functions because the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module already did, and they happen to have the same names as yours.

You use `__name__`.  That's great.  Since you won't be defining functions anymore (because of ^^), this file will be completely useless as a module.  Therefore, I probably wouldn't bother with it.  I *might* define a function to get input and then have a `while True`:

```
def get_answer(num1, num2, op):
    ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            number1 = float(input(...))
            number2 = float(input(...))
        except ValueError:
            print("That is not a number!")
            continue
        operator = input(...)
        answer = get_answer(number1, number2, operator)
        if answer is None:
            print("Invalid operator!")
        else:
            print(answer)
```

That's just a rough draft.  I probably wouldn't do that, but it is a possibility.

Never have a bare `except` unless you are writing your own interpreter.  You should have expectations for what errors you might get.  Let's say you mis-spelled `number1` and said `numberl`.  There would be an error, so it would say `That is not a number!` ... no matter what you type.  What is your expectation?  Of course, it's that the user might type an invalid float.  In that case, use `except ValueError:`

I would use a dictionary for the different operations, and I would use the more standard operator names.  That is, `^` instead of `pow`.  I would also tell the user the options at the beginning instead of telling him each time.  Here is the full program:

```
import operator

operators = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.truediv,
    '%': operator.mod,
    '^': operator.pow,
    '//': operator.floordiv,
    '>': operator.gt,
    '<': operator.lt,
    '=': operator.eq,
    '!=': operator.ne,
    '>=': operator.ge,
    '<=': operator.le,
}

def get_answer(num1, num2, op):
    try:
        return operators[op](num1, num2)
    except IndexError:
        raise ValueError("Invalid operator")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    operator_string = ', '.join(operators)
    print("Valid operators: {}\n".format(operator_string))
    while True:
        try:
            number1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
            number2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("That is not a number!")
            continue
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):
            break # exit
        op = input("Enter an operator: ")
        try:
            print(get_answer(number1, number2, op))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid operator!")
```